# Directory.GetFiles searchOption overload not working

Tags: c#, .net

Just for starters, be aware that I am new to C#, StackOverflow, and programming in general. I'm having trouble with the `Directory.GetFiles` method in `System.IO`. I have all of my code working except for the `searchOption` overload. Here's my current code.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path:"C:/example", searchPattern:"*.txt");

foreach(string name in files) { Console.WriteLine(name); }
```

I'm having trouble because I want the snippet to search the directory 'example' and all of its subdirectories. I've read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that it's supposed to look something like `SearchOption.AllDirectories`, but when I try that in Visual Studio (Professional 2015), IntelliSense pulls up something that looks more like `searchOption:`, and I can't figure out how to put the `AllDirectories` argument into this overload. Anything I do results in one of the following errors.

> What I've tried (the above code with one of these as the third overload):
>
> System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories - Named Argument Specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified.
>
> searchOption:AllDirectories - The name 'AllDirectories' does not exist in the current context.
>
> searchOption:"AllDirectories" - cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.SearchOption'.

And so forth. I've done at least 3 hours of research on the subject on MSDN, Google, StackOverflow, codeproject, and others, and I still can't find the answer.

Comment: You are close.  Take a look here for a code example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There are three overloaded versions. One with a single directory argument, a second with a directory and pattern string, and the third which adds a System.IO.SearchOption. If you want to use the SearchOption parameter, you will need to provide the second pattern argument.

Comment: You really should include the code that gave you those errors as well.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The stuff about searchOption on the left is the code that gave me those errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
string[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(stage_path,"*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the parameter label `searchPattern:` in your method call is due to named parameters, which were introduced in C# 4.0

If you pass all of the parameters in the order described, you don't need to include the labels.

`Directory.GetFiles("C:/example", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);` should produce what you want.

Comment: Actually that's named parameters which allow you to give the parameters in any order you want.  They go hand in hand with optional parameters, but are not the same thing.

Comment: Good point @juharr -- mostly irrelevant to the question asked, but still good to use correct terminology.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew! This did exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @AndrewTheken Unfortunately, I haven't yet reached 15 reputation so SO doesn't allow my votes to be publicly displayed.